# Need formula for a range of cells - to highlight cells based on the presence of a value in another range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula for conditional formatting. It's extremely simple, or so I thought. If cell R4 has any number, such as 1935001011, cell E4 should be highlighted yellow. If there is no value, there should be no highlight. I need to do this for the entire range of cells in column E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

1. Select the range you want
2. Home - Styles - Conditional formatting - Highlighting Cells Rules - More Rules - Use formula....
3. Copy **=$R4<>""**
4. Format - Fill - Select color Apply & Ok!

Comment: @GracePT - Be careful. This just checks if the cell in `R` is **not blank**. It does *not* check if it's a number (`12345`) or a string (`hello my name is Grace PT`).

Comment: I understand. But it does the job. I think that's what was complicating it for me - it really was that simple lol

Comment: @BruceWayne your are absolutely right about this but  in case of accidentally user enter a string or space will give an indication to be corrected. Also in my opinion the number will include alphabetical character if it s represent product code etc

Answer (score 1):

The formula would simply be:

```
=ISNUMBER($R4)
```

And then the Applies To range (change the rows as needed):

```
=$E$4:$E$1000
```

And just choose the conditional formatting options you want.

Comment: Hi BruceWayne (nice name btw) - I meant to say any such number. The condition needs to apply to any number in R4. Thanks.

Comment: @GracePT - Ah, my mistake when reading the post.  See the edit.

Comment: @GracePT - can you be more specific? What didn't work? What if you try `=ISNUMBER(R4)` just as a formula in the spreadsheet, does it return `FALSE`?

Comment: it did nothing really :(

Comment: @GracePT ...What do you mean? In `A1`, put `=ISNUMBER(R4)`.  What does the formula output??

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting ColumnE and applying a CF formula rule to it of:

```
=ISNUMBER(R1)
```